# How to get data from JQuery/Html in Adobe Air 2.5?

Tags: jquery, html, apache-flex, air, adobe

is it possible to get any information/text from JQuery Alert or a simple textbox (per ID)?

My Problem: 
I took a picture in Air 2.5, save it to my disk, load a locale HTML file with the new picture and JQuery detects faces on it. Then I place the coordinates of the face into the html box or show it in an alert box. How is it possible to get these coordinates from HTML/JQuery? Facedetection with JQuery needs 1-2seconds in the browser.

PS: I want to do this without php. only air, flash, HTML or JQuery or another Plugin (without an extra server/apache).

Damian

Comment: I am 100% sure you can in flash action script but not sure about Air I haven't explored in that

Comment: What does this question have to do w/ Flex?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok solution is very simple. HTML access via javascript:

```
htmlBox.htmlLoader.window.document.getElementById('my_id').firstChild.nodeValue;
```

htmlBox: type of `<mx:html>`

my_id: e.g. `<p id="my_id">information</p>`